# Displaying multiple markers in google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display multiple markers on my Google map and my latitude and longitude will be coming from the database. I have been trying for days but I can't seem to make it work. 
Could anyone please help me? I would really appreciate it.

This is my **PHP** code:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT latlong FROM terminal");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
     $lat[] = $row1[0];

$latlen = sizeof($lat);

$result2=mysql_query("SELECT longitude FROM terminal");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_NUM))
    $longi[] = $row2[0];


for ($x=0;$x<$latlen;$x++){
    $latitude = $lat[$x];
    $longitude = $longi[$x];
}
```

But the problem is, I don't know how the loop will work on my **JavaScript** code:

```
var latitude = "<?php print_r ($latitude); ?>";
var longitude = "<?php print_r ($longitude); ?>";

var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', latitude,longitude ], 
];
```

This code only shows 1 marker. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great tutorial on what you are looking to do.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: aren't there any other solution that is closer to my codes?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to do it that way? There are many benefits to using the tutorial like quicker loading time and easier to debug among other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to gen each marker as json data
fist make php file to return array to json with json_encode($markers)

```
{
    "markers": [
        {
            "latitude": 57.7973333,
            "longitude": 12.0502107,
            "title": "Angered",
            "content": "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
            "latitude": 57.6969943,
            "longitude": 11.9865,
            "title": "Gothenburg",
            "content": "Lorem ipsum"
        }
    ]
}
```

then use loop in jquery to pin each marker on map.

```
$.getJSON( 'map_data_file.php', function(data) {
    $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
      //Populate each marker
    });
});
```

i think you get the idea